# Using callbacks function from multi modules

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have an example code :

```js
app.get('/webhook', function(req, res) {
  if (req.query['hub.mode'] === 'subscribe' &&
      req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VALIDATION_TOKEN) {
    console.log("Validating webhook");
    res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  } else {
    console.error("Failed validation. Make sure the validation tokens match.");
    res.sendStatus(403);          
  }  
});
```

Then now i want to break callbacks function to new module.I save this function in Verify.js:

```js
function ValidationToken(req, res) {
  if (req.query['hub.mode'] === 'subscribe' &&
      req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VALIDATION_TOKEN) {
    console.log("Validating webhook");
    res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  } else {
    console.error("Failed validation. Make sure the validation tokens match.");
    res.sendStatus(403);          
  }  
}
exports.ValidationToken=ValidationToken;
```

But now i can not use this function for callbacks :

```js
var VefiryQuery=require("./Facebook/VerifyRequest");
 var ValidationToken=VefiryQuery.ValidationToken();
app.get('/webhook', ValidationToken(req,res){});
```

Then i get error : req and res are not defined.
How can i break it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to call the `ValidationToken()` function before passing it as a callback:

```
var VefiryQuery = require("./Facebook/VerifyRequest");
var ValidationToken = VefiryQuery.ValidationToken;
app.get('/webhook', ValidationToken);
```

Comment: In function ValidationToken(req, res) ,  i get new errors : TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: Are you sure that `ValidationToken()` is called only from the code you posted? It looks like there's at least one another place where you call it directly without passing arguments: `var v = ValidationToken();`

Comment: Yes.Thank you so much